# DropboxSDK: error reading stored keychain value (-34018)

Tags: ios, sdk, dropbox

I am using Dropbox Api 3.0 and Sync + Datastore and its giving me an error abut readint the keychain values. I am using ios 8.0 anyone know whats going on ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a known keychain bug in iOS 8 beta 1. Download iOS 8 beta 2 and it'll probably resolve.

Comment: I just got this error on iOS 8.3 production. It's a long standing bug that hasn't been fixed.